# React in Redux not effect Dispatch() method onclick on Add button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Add.js**

'+' button on click to not effect in state.value

```html
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { AddNumber } from "./action/index";
export const Add=()=>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return(
        <>
           <button onClick={() => dispatch(AddNumber())}>+</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

**action->index.js**

```html
export const AddNumber =()=>{
    return{
        type:"increment"
    }
}
```

**Reducer->index.js**

```html
import ChangeNumber from "./UpDown";

import { combineReducers} from "redux"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: ChangeNumber
})

export default rootReducer;
```

**Reducer->updown.js**

```html
const initialState ={value:0};

const ChangeNumber = (state=initialState,action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'increment': return state.value + 1;
        case 'decriment': return state.value - 1;
        default:return state;
    }

}
export default ChangeNumber;
```

**Store.js**

```html
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './reducer';
const Store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer })

export default Store;
```

**index.js**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52fFO.png)

**input.js**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyXWR.png)

Comment: Please attach code samples not images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducer->updown.js

File In return object.
So, **return {state.value-1}**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `bindActionCreators` when using `useDispatch`. Simply run dispatch with your action creator function:

```js
export const Add=()=>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return(
        <>
           <button onClick={() => dispatch(AddNumber())}>+</button>
        </>
    )
}
```